# Boost TCP Server not reading all incoming data

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, asynchronous, boost

I am making a Boost TCP Server and following this example.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

I realised that not all the messages sent by client are received by the server and after further reading i realised the problem lies with this function.

```
void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }
```

Since we are using socket_.async_read_some this function can exit before reading all the messages.

Can this function be modified or how should i make a server which will read all the incoming messages.

Comment: Use free function `async_read` but then reading operation is blocking, until 1024 (value of `max_length`) bytes are read. If you know delimiter of messages (for example new line character) you can use `async_read_until`, it is more flexible.

Comment: @rafix07 i am creating a new thread for the Server operations and i want to keep reading as long as application is running.